# IReport Dataset Parameters from Parent

Tags: dataset, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using IReport 4.5.0 and I have this report having a Crosstab. This Crosstab is connected to a Dataset with parameters to be used on the `WHERE` of the SQL.

The problem is that I cannot problem pass the value of my defined parameters from parent to the dataset. Though both have the same name, the value isn't passed. How can I pass parameters from parent to dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have only one (1) Crosstab on the report. I have noticed when selecting `Main report dataset` as the Dataset of the Crosstab, answered my question.

But I still have problem the same problem when multiple Dataset(s) are involved in a report wherein the parameters of these Dataset(s) must come from the Parent parameters.